# Postgresql Special Order BY

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I need to use an `ORDER BY` on a table but keep some special rows on top.
The rows that have `name='developer'` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'developer' THEN '0' ELSE name END
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do the ORDER BY without the usage of a CASE:

```
ORDER BY 
  name = 'developer' DESC,
  name ASC;
```

Comment: This also avoids the unstated assumption about the nature of the `name`s that the accepted answer forgot to note.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'developer' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name
```